# Como manipular mensagens de erro do jquery validate?

Tags: jquery, label, jquery.validate

Eis o caso: Tenho dois inputs, os dois estão validados com o validate, um eu preciso que mostre a msg de erro e mude a cor da borda, o outro só preciso que mude a cor da boar, sem msg de erro.
É possível fazer isso? Pois mesmo não citando o input no messages o label aparece (em branco mas aparece), e acaba com meu layout todo. Gostaria da ajuda de alguém se possível. Obrigada.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você está usando o form_for ou simple_form. Adiciona a view do código no teu post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode tentar ocultar o a mensagem de erro:

```
$('#ID_DO_INPUT').siblings('label.error').css('display', 'none');
```

Comment: Isso eu já tinha tentado e não deu certo. continua o mesmo caso.

Comment: Tem q chamar após após cada método de validação.